# Listview dateformat

Tags: date, listview, yii2, format

In my yii2 I'm having a listview:

```
<?php
echo\yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $provider,
'summary' => false,
'itemView' => function($model)
{       
        return'
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">'.$model->title.'</h4>
            <p  class="list-group-item-text">'.$model->date.'</p>
          </a>
        </div>';        
},  
]);
?>
```

My problem is that the date is alsways schown in the format yyyy-mm-dd. I want the date in the format dd.mm.yyyy.
Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Yii i18n Formatter

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asDate('2017-09-24', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

Refer [Yii i18n Formatter asDate()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#asDate()-detail)

As like below

```
<?php

echo \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $provider,
    'summary' => false,
    'itemView' => function($model) {       
       return '
          <div class="list-group">
             <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">' . $model->title . '</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">' . Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->date, 'dd.mm.yyyy') . '</p>
             </a>
          </div>';        
     },  
]);

?>
```

Comment: Where do I have to write this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime()`

```
$date = '2017-10-10';
$newdate = date('d.m.Y',strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Where do I have to write this?